# Chrome- won't seek audio when already preloading

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio

I'm using HTML5 audio. Everything is going swell, our server supports HTTP ranges and the audio streams/buffers correctly, etc.

There's just one slight problem with seeking. When you seek to a new position, Chrome sometimes doesn't seek there when there's an existing request going. It just completely ignores the request to seek, so the user can't actually play back at the new seek position.

How can I make Chrome always stop the existing request and start serving for the new seek result?

Chrome seems to respond to the seeked() event, but I've noticed by logging the events that it's this event which is sometimes not fired promptly. I tried manually firing the seeked() event, but that does not seem to be helping.

I found an answer recommending playing and then pausing for a similar-sounding issue for video elements. Unfortunately I did not find this to have any effect for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've mitigated this issue by reducing the request size. Previously, when the browser requested a range, we pretty much just sent back the range it asked for. Now I cap the size at 100kb. Chrome still rarely interrupts a request to seek; but now even on a slow connection each request is still just a couple of seconds, so it's not tremendously unusable given the connection quality.